# Why is the splat/unary operator changing the assigned value a when p is called before *a = ""?

Tags: ruby

To give a little context around how I understand the problem.

Using splat collect on a string sends :to_a or :to_ary to the String

```
class String
  def method_missing method, *args, &block
    p method #=> :to_ary
    p args   #=> []
    p block  #=> nil
  end
end

*b = "b"
```

So I was thinking that redefining the :to_ary method would be what I'm after.

```
class String
  def to_ary
    ["to_a"]
  end
end

p *a = "a" #=> "a"
p a        #=> "a"

*b = "b"
p b        #=> ["to_a"]
```

Now this confuses me to no end.

Printing the result from the *a = "a" changes the value assigned to a?

To demonstrate further

```
class String
  def to_ary
    [self.upcase!]
  end
end

p *a = "a" #=> "a"
p a        #=> "a"

*b = "b"
p b        #=> ["B"]
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Very interesting question! Ruby takes this expression:

```
 p *a = "a"
```

and translates it to something like this:

```
 temp = (a = "a")
 p *temp
```

So the first thing that happens is that `a` gets assigned to `"a"`, and then the *result* of the assignment expression which is `"a"` gets splatted and sent to `p`. Since `p`'s default behaviour when sent multiple arguments is just to iterate over and print each one, you only see `"a"` appear.

In short, it follows a "assign then splat" order of evaluation. So `a` gets assigned to `"a"` before the string gets splatted.

When you don't have a function call however, it is interpreted as something like this:

```
# *a = "a" gets interpreted as:
temp = "a"
a = *temp
```

This follows a "splat then assign" order of evaluation. So `a` gets assigned *after* the string gets splatted.

You can see what's being received by a function by going like this:

```
def foo *args
  puts args.inspect
end

foo *a = "a"    # outputs ["a"]
a               # outputs "a"
```

Hope this clears up what's going on!

In short (thanks to Mark Reed):

```
p *a = "a"    # interpreted as: p(*(a = "a"))
*a = "a"      # interpreted as: a = *("a")
```

Comment: Right.  It's all about the precedence.  `p *a = "a"` means `p(*(a = "a"))`, not `p( *a = "a" )`.